# How can I use DS.RESTAdapter with ember cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I created model in models/application.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And created adapter in adapters/application.js:

```
import Ember from "ember";
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://site.work/rest/v1/'
});
```

Route in routes/application.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.all('application');
});
```

Template in templates/application.hbs

```
{{#each item in model}}
<li>{{item.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

app.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Resolver from 'ember/resolver';
import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers';

Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true;

var App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: 'chat', // TODO: loaded via config
  Resolver: Resolver
});

loadInitializers(App, 'chat');

export default App;
```

router.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: ChatENV.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.route("application");
});

export default Router;
```

JSON example from the server: `{"application":[{"id":"1","name":"qwe"},{"id":"2","name":"qwe2"}]}`

But my model is empty and I can't find any xhr requests in developer tool.

How should I use DS.RESTAdapter in Ember Cli?

Note: When I add this line into router it's works:

```
this.store.push('application',{'id':5, 'name':'Is this a question?'});
```

Comment: Well, are you doing anything that would actually cause a network request? They don't happen by magic.

Comment: ember-cli build application and should customize adapter like in this guide http://emberjs.com/guides/models/customizing-adapters/

Comment: What I am asking, is do you have a route defined which will request a model which will actually instigate the network request?

Comment: yes, I have route application and with line return this.store.all('application');

Comment: Share the exact code needed to reproduce your issue (all of it, but not more).

Comment: `this.store.all` will not make any requests. Read the manual.

Comment: Thanks, this.store.find('application',1); it works, but how I can load all rows

Comment: Did you try `this.store.find('application')`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the name of your model (`application`) is causing weird behaviour, since ember(-cli) also uses this name as root for things such as adapter, route, etc.

Apart from that, I would define my adapter as follows:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'rest/v1'
});
```

and then start your server with:

```
ember server --proxy=http://site.work
```